# How can i nest another SQL COUNT into this?

Tags: sql, count

I have this code that works as planned.  Gives me the "source" and how many apps for each source.

```
SELECT source, COUNT(1) as Cnt
    FROM apps
    WHERE monthyear = 'October2018' 
    GROUP BY source
```

> OUTPUT is ['Store1', 1], ['Store2', 5], ['Store3', 3],

I have another row named "sold" on the same table that i would like to count within each Store of how many sold = 1 so i get this output:

> Source, Apps, Sold ['Store1', 1, 0], ['Store2', 5, 3], ['Store3', 3,
>   1]

Comment: You have another row named `sold`? Or maybe you meant a table? What's the structure of that table? How would you connect data from it to `apps` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, then you have a column in the `apps` table called `sold` which is presumably a Boolean value, and you want your existing query to return the number of records for each distinct `source` value for which the `sold` flag is set. In that case you need a conditional count, like so:

```
select
    source,
    count(1) as Cnt,
    count(case when Sold = 1 then 1 end) as CountSold
from
    apps
where
    monthyear = 'October2018' 
group by
    source;
```

Then you just update your code to include the new `CountSold` value wherever you want it. Let me know if I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!